# how can i change the font size of autofill text

Tags: css, input, autofill

i am trying to overwrite the default styles browsers use for autofiling and add my own
by using this

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #080808;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1000px 1000px white;
  font-size: 1rem;}
```

but no matter how much i try the font size won't apply, is there any solutions?
i have already tried to use input:-webkit-autofill::first-line which did not work.

Comment: i could not find any way to fix it , if the problem annoys you you can disable auto filling by using  autocomplete="off" on the input field.